# Subscription URL doesn't work in Apollo Graphql Subscription Server

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo

I have a graphql server uses `apollo-server-express`. Below is the code for a basic graphql request response mode.

```
const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
  context: async ({ connection }) => {
    if (connection) {
      return {
        ...connection.context,
      };
    }
    return null;
  },
});

server.applyMiddleware({ app, path: '/graphql' });
```

It works fine. You can see it uses `applyMiddleware` to make use express server. I am able to open the graphiql on `http://localhost:8080/graphql` url and test it from there. And later I added subscription support in my code:

```
const { SubscriptionServer } = require('subscriptions-transport-ws');
const { createServer } = require('http');
const ws = createServer(app);
SubscriptionServer.create({...}, {
    server: ws,
    path: '/subscriptions',
  });
```

Once I've done that, my app functionality works fine but I can't test it on the `graphiql` playground. It complains about the subscription URL which is always `http://localhost:8080/graphql` rather than `http://localhost:8080/subscriptions`?

I found that some people say to use this code:

```
app.use(‘/graphiql’, graphiqlExpress({
  endpointURL: ‘/graphql’,
  subscriptionsEndpoint: `ws://localhost:3000/subscriptions`,
}));
```

but my app is using `applyMiddleware`. I wonder how I can make it work in my case.

Comment: Please note that GraphQL Playground is based on GraphiQL, but they are not the same thing. Apollo Server used to include a GraphiQL endpoint, but now uses Playground instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The options for your GraphQL Playground endpoint are passed to the ApolloServer constructor, as shown [in the docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/api/apollo-server/#parameters).

```
const server = new ApolloServer({
  playground: {
    subscriptionEndpoint: 'your custom subscription endpoint',
    // other GraphQL Playground options
  },
  ...
});
```

The available options are shown [here](https://github.com/prisma-labs/graphql-playground#usage).